# Implementing Future interface for shared computation

Tags: java, multithreading, future

I'm implementing the `Future<Collection<Integer>>` interface in order to share the result of some bulk computation among all thread in the application.

In fact, I intended to just put an instance of a class implemetnting `Future<Collection<Integer>>` into an ApplicationScope object so that any other thread which need the result just ask for the `Future`  from the `object` and call the method `get()` on it, therefore using the computation performed by some another thread.

My question is about implementing the `cancel` method. For now, I would write something like that:

```
public class CustomerFutureImpl implements Future<Collection<Integer>>{

    private Thread computationThread;
    private boolean started;
    private boolean cancelled;
    private Collection<Integer> computationResult;

    private boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning){
        if( computationResult != null )
            return false;
        if( !started ){
            cancelled = true;
            return true;
        } else {
            if(mayInterruptIfRunning)
                 computationThread.interrupt();
        }
    }

    //The rest of the methods
}
```

But the method implementation doesn't satisfy the documentation of the [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) because we need to throw `CancellationException` in any thread awaiting for the result (has called the `get()` method).

Should I add another one field like `private Collection<Thread> waitingForTheResultThreads;` and then interrupt each thread from the `Collection`, catch interrupted exception and then `throw new CancellationException()`?

The thing is that such a solution seems kind of wierd to me... Not sure about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you should avoid implementing `Future` directly at all.  Concurrency code is *very* hard to get right, and frameworks for distributed execution - notably [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) - will provide `Future` instances referencing the units of work you care about.

You may know that already and are intentionally creating a new similar service, but I feel it's important to call out that for the *vast* majority of use cases, you should not need to define your own `Future` implementation.

You might want to look at the concurrency tools Guava provides, in particular [`ListenableFuture`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained), which is a sub-interface of `Future` that provides additional features.

---

Assuming that you really do want to define a custom `Future` type, use Guava's [`AbstractFuture`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractFuture.html) implementation as a starting point, so that you don't have to reinvent the complex details you're running into.

To your specific question, if you look at the [implementation of `AbstractFuture.get()`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/42f98108422f92cb6620d6f22ff78d7ce491d76e/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractFuture.java#L443), you'll see that it's implemented with a `while` loop that looks for `value` to become non-null, at which time it calls `getDoneValue()` which either returns the value or raises a `CancellationException`.  So essentially, each thread that is blocking on a call to `Future.get()` is polling the `Future.value` field every so often and raising a `CancellationException` if it detects that the `Future` has been cancelled.  There's no need to keep track of a `Collection<Thread>` or anything of the sort, since each thread can inspect the state of the `Future` independently, and return or throw as needed.

Comment: BTW, I didn't implement it actually. I created less verbose interface having just three methods: `public T ensureResult();` which starts the compution if it has not been yet and waiting for it to be completed if some thread has started it. And methods `isStarted` and `done()` returning the state of the computation.

Comment: What would you say about such a solution?

Comment: Sounds like a weaker `Future`.  I can't say whether that's a good solution or not without a fuller understanding of your goals, but in general I'd encourage reuse rather than reinvention.  [`Supplier`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Supplier.html), `ListenableFuture`, and very occasionally `AbstractFuture` (along with their associated utility classes) ought to do most everything you'd need.

Comment: _Sounds like a weaker Future_ Exactly, it is. Future is too verbose for that purpose. In fact I don't have to provide time-limited version of [get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) as well as I obligated implementors of the interface to perform computations _**synchronously**_ (i.e. if it has not been started yet, the caller-thread cannot create another thread to perform it). I'm not sure if such a requirements too restrictive, but I thought that it was a good one for "shared-computation".

Comment: I got familar with the references you provided and honesty I don't see how I could reuse it. The only thought I have is I could extend Supplier to provide the checking methods. Is that what you menat?